# tensorflow - Why is the shape of the matrix of a BasicRNNCell not equal to (n_hidden x n_input)?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I've just started learning tensorflow and I tried to build a simple rnn. The below is all the code you need to reproduce the problem I'm experiencing.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
rnn = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(110, 
                                  activation=tf.sigmoid)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[20, 5, 2], name='x')
xt = tf.transpose(x)
x_split = [x_temp[:,0,:] for x_temp in tf.split(1, 5, xt)[::-1]]
h_list, _ = tf.nn.rnn(rnn, x_split, dtype=tf.float32)

tf.all_variables()[0].get_shape()
# TensorShape([Dimension(130), Dimension(110)])
x_split
# [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze:0' shape=(2, 20) dtype=float32>,
#  <tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_1:0' shape=(2, 20) dtype=float32>,
#  <tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_2:0' shape=(2, 20) dtype=float32>,
#  <tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_3:0' shape=(2, 20) dtype=float32>,
#  <tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_4:0' shape=(2, 20) dtype=float32>]
```

Why is that the dimension of the matrix? I would expect it to be 20 x 110, since the inputs have dimension 20.

```
tf.__version__
# 0.10.0rc0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BasicRNNCell` has the following mechanics (as per [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L198)):

```
"""Most basic RNN: output = new_state = activation(W * input + U * state + B)."""
```

The variable `RNN/BasicRNNCell/Linear/Matrix:0` you checked the size of is an inner RNNCell variable, encoding transition from state to state. Thus, it accepts both input of size 20 and the previous state of size 110 and outputs the next state of size 110, so it is encoded as a `130 x 110` matrix.

In other words, it concatenates `U` and `W` from the comment.